# edit header component of Transfer in Ant Design library

Tags: reactjs, antd

using transfer component within free version of ant design and trying to change header text of table

[image]

how can it be done?

Its very poor of AntDesign documents there is no mention about it, I dont wanna believe its not exist,

demo sandbox link;
https://codesandbox.io/s/7uc1g?file=/index.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use title and selectAllLabels prop to edit the headers.Both the props accept arrays. (Check your antd version if you still doesn't able to use those props)

```
 titles={[<Tag color="geekblue">I am on Left</Tag>, <Tag color="geekblue">I am on right</Tag>]}

 selectAllLabels={[
                ({ selectedCount, totalCount }) => (
                  <span>
                    {selectedCount} of {totalCount}
                    <Tag color="geekblue">left</Tag>
                  </span>
                ), ({ selectedCount, totalCount }) => (
                  <span>
                    {selectedCount} of {totalCount}
                    <Tag color="geekblue">right</Tag>
                  </span>
                )
              ]}
```

[image]

Sample Codebox

https://codesandbox.io/s/table-transfer-ant-design-demo-v4wxj?file=/index.js:2936-3517

Comment: your answer better solution focused and eloborated clearly, Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for solution. Somehow I am unable to remove filter arrows.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the source code: 
https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/transfer/index.tsx

Maybe try playing around with the "titles" props or locale.titles and see what happens,

other props:

```
export interface TransferProps {
  prefixCls?: string;
  className?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  dataSource: TransferItem[];
  targetKeys?: string[];
  selectedKeys?: string[];
  render?: TransferRender;
  onChange?: (targetKeys: string[], direction: string, moveKeys: string[]) => void;
  onSelectChange?: (sourceSelectedKeys: string[], targetSelectedKeys: string[]) => void;
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
  listStyle: ((style: ListStyle) => React.CSSProperties) | React.CSSProperties;
  operationStyle?: React.CSSProperties;
  titles?: string[];
  operations?: string[];
  showSearch?: boolean;
  filterOption?: (inputValue: string, item: TransferItem) => boolean;
  locale?: Partial<TransferLocale>;
  footer?: (props: TransferListProps) => React.ReactNode;
  rowKey?: (record: TransferItem) => string;
  onSearch?: (direction: TransferDirection, value: string) => void;
  onScroll?: (direction: TransferDirection, e: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLUListElement>) => void;
  children?: (props: TransferListBodyProps) => React.ReactNode;
  showSelectAll?: boolean;
  selectAllLabels?: SelectAllLabel[];
}
```

Comment: I have checked it already, it not accepts jsx, couldn't edit it

Comment: well anyway, its possible if you add the titles={["title left", "title right"]} prop to the transfer, and with some css class manipulation you can get rid of the "12 items"