# Custom header control/footer of Transfer in Ant Design library

Tags: antd

I have the following Table Transfer control with antd design.

I would like to add a list box select on the top where I could filter by Groups. Currently this is what I have but it looks like there are too many header items (groups filter, item count - 1135 Document Types, Search here text box.
I would like to consolidate the three items with some custom header control. Any ideas? This might be an overkill.

Or

How about moving the Document Types count to the bottom?
Only Doucment Groups and Search here would show up as the header. 1135 Document Types would be the footer. This is a sandbox. I need help with moving the
https://codesandbox.io/s/7uc1g?file=/index.js

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: If anyone is looking for answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61232765/edit-header-component-of-transfer-in-ant-design-library